# Expand intellisense method overloads

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

How do I display expanded list of method overloads in intellisense popup, like this: 
?

[image: http://img1.uploadscreenshot.com/images/orig/1/2300511497-orig.png]

Comment: Where did you get the image from? Perhaps it's a 3rd party user extension.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair from [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NcjmRo2WJbA&feature=player_detailpage#t=130s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't free, but resharper will do this for you, plus tons of other features

[image]

Comment: I'm the only dev on my team without ReSharper.. I just ... never got used to it.

Comment: I never thought I would...and now I can't live without it.  It saves an incredible amount of time once you understand what it's doing for you.